Unwanted backgroud gradient borders
im creating simple chatbox with gradient color behavior like on messenger. I did it but on some resolutions i can see unwated "borders".

At the beggining i thought its some devtools problem because i can only see them on mobile setting in browser but i havent seen them on localhost on real phones.
But these lines exist all the time and i can see them also on pc with background blur

ChatBox:
const messages = ['123', '456', '789', '123', '456']
 <section className='flex size-full relative overflow-hidden border-b border-grey w-full'>
         <div
             className={'flex-1 greyScrollBar mb-2 flex flex-col-reverse relative'}
              style={{background: 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #550029, #aa3232, #e3b100)'}}
          >
             <div className='flex-1'>
                {messages.map((message, index) => {
                    return (
                         <TextBox
                            message={message}
                            key={index}
                         />
                   )
             })}       
            </div>
         </div>
</section>

TextBox:
 <div className={'flex flex-col'}>
            <div
                className={`flex overflow-hidden message max-lg:select-none blur-sm`}
                
            >
                <div
                    className={`rounded-3xl bg-transparent bg-grey my-[1px] max-w-[80%] shadow-[0_0_0_16px_#121212] relative flex items-center w-fit overflow-hidden`}
                >
                    <span
                        className={
                            'w-fit text-sm my-2 mx-3.5 font-medium'
                        }
                    >
                        {message}
                    </span>
                </div>
                // Covering left space gradient on right side with actual color
                <div className='flex-1 bg-darkGrey'></div>
            </div>
        </div>

The contept of this feature is to "cut" unwanted gradient with boxshadow or outline to get border radius shape message
I tried changing background gradient to backgroundImage Setting 0 value margins, borders, paddings or negative values on TextBox but also on ChatBox. background-origin: border-box; from related questions or backgroud-attachment

You can try removing border from the section element here
<section className='flex size-full relative overflow-hidden border-b border-grey w-full'>

like this
<section className='flex size-full relative overflow-hidden w-full'>

But I am not sure if it is going to solve the problem.

unfortunately it has nothing to do with these gradient borders, as u can see, borders are also between items 
